# Is it possible to just compile SCSS to CSS in vue app?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I'm trying to use some dynamic styling in my Vue.JS application. The idea is to build SCSS themes to static CSS and use it as  in my template to switch themes.

Since I'm using bulma as css framework all my styles look the same as:

```
theme-1.scss

$primary: wheat;
@import 'bulma/bulma';
```

The current solution is just a bootstrapped vue application with default webpack config. The only time I was able to build scss to css and use it further was the following config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        functions: [
            './src/index.js', 
            './src/scss/theme1.scss', 
            './src/scss/theme2.scss'
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        filename: 'dist/js/[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'dist/css/[name].css',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Unfortunately I can't use multiple entries in vue app. And it also seems to me is not the right way to work with single page application

Since i'm absolutely new to webpack and vue-loader I think that I do everything wrong and think in the wrong way. Maybe some plugin exists which do definitely the same thing as I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for this issue:

in my vue.config.js I made the following:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.entry('theme') // you can add here as much themes as you want
            .add('./src/theme.scss')
            .end();
    },

    css: {
        extract: { 
            filename: '[name].css', // to have a name related to a theme
            chunkFilename: 'css/[name].css' 
        },
        modules: false,
        sourceMap: true
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've typically not used file-loader in my CSS setup; instead I've always used a style-loader, css-loader with MiniCSSExtractPlugin:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#advanced-configuration-example

Give that setup configuration for MiniCSSExtractPlugin a review.
MiniCSSExtractPlugin is a nice to have, so the most important thing to note is that you are missing the css-loader (which should be used instead of file-loader).

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you. file-loader was used only to check if multiple css extraction is possible. (that was an attempt without vue)
I've checked my vue.config and saw that I already have a mini-css-extract-plugin. but it generates only one css file named app.css (since my main component is App.vue)
But I want my webpackto build app.css and (theme1/theme2/etc).css simultaneously